# Is it possible to respond to when a queue has been auto deleted?

Tags: rabbitmq

If you set `x-expires` on a queue to auto-delete the queue if it has been unused for a period of time, is it possible to be notified of that event in any way?  I would like to take some cleanup action when a queue is deleted in this fashion.  Ideally, by a message being posted to some exchange/queue that I can consume.

For [reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html), `x-expires` with queues:

> The `x-expires` argument to `queue.declare` controls for how long a queue can be unused before it is automatically deleted. Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not been redeclared, and basic.get has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period.  The server guarantees that the queue will be deleted, if unused for at least the expiration period.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no built-in way to do this on the RabbitMQ-side.  You would need to use the API to get a list of queues, and then compare snapshots of this list over time.

I can't think of a scenario where it would be useful to know when a queue is auto-deleted. In my view, that is already an automatic resource cleanup feature. Who would want to know about this event (client or server)? How would you expect to recover if you somehow "missed" one of these notifications? Perhaps there is a better, more deterministic way of achieving your goals.

Would you be able to provide your use-case, so possibly a more useful alternative solution can be suggested?